# Page with Ajax Loaded Div Doesn't Display Scrollbar

Tags: ajax, html, scrollbar

I have a page with a couple DIVs with contents loaded via ajax. After the contents loaded, the page doesn't dislay the scrollbar to show all the DIV contents (I can't scroll down to see the rest of the content.)  I tried with Firefox and IE. All have the same problem. Is there away I can fix this?

Comment: please post the code that you have so we can help understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set style on the div or class?

```
overflow: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the HTML and CSS, all I can offer is a few suggestions:

1. Maybe you have unclosed tags.
2. The div style might prevent correct display.  What's the overflow set to?
3. If you're loading into a div that's in a document *in an iframe,* you get this kind of stuff a lot.

Can you scroll around the div with TAB or by mouse-selecting its contents?  Maybe the content isn't even being loaded fully.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS I had the position of the div as fixed

```
div.query_res{
position:fixed;
top:40px;
left:445px;
}
```

changed it to

```
div.query_res{
position:relative;
top:40px;
left:445px;
}
```

And all was good.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old, but just in case some else gets here, as me, you have to redraw the page, as the calculations to add a scroll has been already made. So you have to tell the browser to redraw as the content size has changed. You can test if this is the case by changing the size of the window, if doing so gets back the scroll bar, then redraw after generating the DIV or whatever you are generating.